# DHCP server not assigning IPs - Linux (CentOS)

Tags: linux, dhcp, dhcp-server

I am having a main issue with the DHCP server.  It is not assigning IPs and the dhcp.leases file is increasing in size as it is logging multiple entries for same IP. Started and stopped the service and still, same result.

I have tried everything possible.

Any idea what's causing this problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you paste your dhcp logs here ?

Comment: I have no specific logs for dhcp, but I can put up the /var/log/messages one, will that be ok?

Comment: use grep to filter for lines generated by dhcp, for example, `grep -i 'dhcp' /var/log/messages`

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem. Some other guy setup another DHCP Server on the same network and it was causing conflict with this one.

Put down the other server, problem solved!